# How to interpret which factors should be extracted following EFA in SPSSFA

Tags: spss

My apologies if this sounds..... obvious but my first time running these..I have completed EFA..got the factor loadings and extracted variables etc.But how do I interpret or relate these back to my main data...for instance if I was running it on the most liked fruit (apples, bananas,orange, grapes,kiwi,pears,lemons),If based on the analysis tables it's required to extract 2x fruit based on eigenvalues......How would I know which of the fruit to exclude based on the original data.....Many Thanks we learn everyday.....